# Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h while installing 'elance' gem on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I have facing some problem with curl and curb on windows.

working on following environment :
ruby 1.9.3
rails 4.0.3

and added 'elance' gem with gemfile but after added this gem got following error. i need a solution for window environment.

Error details :

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
    c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    checking for curl-config... no
    checking for main() in -lcurl... no
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.

 Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
    --with-curl-dir
    --without-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include
    --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib
    --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
    --with-curllib
    --without-curllib
extconf.rb:23:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)


An error occurred while installing curb (0.8.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install curb -v '0.8.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am stuck here with this error. can you please any one can resolve and help me out with windows.

Comment: Did you install http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/ ?

Comment: yes, i have installed it already

Answer (score 0):

Download and install **cURL** for Windows on the [cURL download page - Win32 section](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32). The ZIP-file contains a curl.exe that you can run and it is the required dependancy that you need.